# Translating SQL to lambda expression

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

How can I translate this to a lambda expression? Can anyone please help?

```
SELECT 
    p.*
FROM
    db.MainProduct p 
WHERE
    p.id IN (SELECT ms.MainProductId 
             FROM db.MainProductToSupplierProduct ms)
    AND (p.description LIKE '%' + @filter + '%' 
         OR Coalesce(@filter,'') = '')
```

Comment: you can try linqpad https://www.linqpad.net/ it can help translate your sql.

Comment: thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or in query syntax:

```
var ans = from p in db.MainProduct where (from ms in db.MainProductToSupplierProduct select ms.MainProductId).Contains(p.id) && (filter == "" || p.description.Contains(filter)) select p;
```

Not sure that is the most efficient way, a less literal translation would use a join:

```
var ans = from p in db.MainProduct join ms in db.MainProductToSupplierProduct on p.id equals ms.MainProductId where filter == "" || p.description.Contains(filter) select p;
```

This is a left semi join and the best way to implement that is probably an `EXISTS` in SQL - it may be faster than join:

```
var ans = from p in db.MainProduct where db.MainProductToSupplierProduct.Any(ms => ms.MainProductId == p.id) && (filter == "" || p.description.Contains(filter)) select p;
```

Comment: it works.. thanks a lot!

However, I have a question. 

              SELECT 
                    p.*
              FROM
               db.MainProduct p  
           WHERE
              p.id NOT IN (SELECT ms.MainProductId 
                FROM db.MainProductToSupplierProduct ms)
                AND (p.description LIKE '%' + @filter + '%' 
                OR Coalesce(@filter,'') = '')

Is there a substitute for NOT IN as well ?

Comment: Actually I had a typo in the third sample that was essentially NOT IN - it had `!.Any()` which means NOT ANY(matches). You could also put a `!` (not) in from of the `.Contains()` expression in the first example (in front of the left paren beginning the sub-query) to say NOT IN more literally.

Comment: if i put a not in front of contains, the compiler throws an error. I put a not (!) after where clause and then it works

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably wasn't clear - the `!` does go immediately after the `where` keyword and just before the expression ending in `.Contains()`. The `!` binds to the `(from ...Contains(...)` and just affects the left hand side of the `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

Below code can help you out

```
var filteredMainProduct= MainProduct.Where(t => MainProductToSupplierProduct.Any(z => z.MainProductId == t.id) && @filter != null ? t.description.Contains(@filter) : t.FareBasisDescription.Contains(""));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I made some changes here and there and it works